Re applying from US visa from a different country
I’ve recently relocated to London with my husband from India.
I had applied for a US visa appointment in India in Sept 2023 and I’ve got an appointment in January 2025. I had applied along with my mother who currently lives in India.
So given the circumstances, I won’t be able to appear for my visa interview in India as I live in London and I would like to change the location for my visa interview to London so I can appear for the interview in London using the same application. So do I just need to restart my DS160?
My mother can continue with her appointment in India on the same date if we can split it.
Or is it advisable to keep the old US visa appointment in India and apply for a fresh DS-160 from London?
Also, is it advisable to keep two US visa applications open from different countries as I would like my application to go smoothly.
Please advise
Will I need to pay the fee again in Uk? Can my mom continue with her appointment in India?

Given the circumstances, there are couple of things which I have listed down:

If you and your mother have taken appointments separately (not as a group) your mom can continue with her visa appointment.
If you have taken it as group appointment (one appointment confirmation for both), then you both have to appear at the same time.
If you have a face-to-face interview in the embassy, you cannot process the visa from a different location other than actual location in the appointment confirmation.
You do not need the new DS-160 unless there is a change in any detail you have entered previously. You can use same DS-160 for a new appointment.
You would not be able to keep the old appointment and take new. You would need to cancel the existing and start a new application.

My advice:
Contact the USCIS via the Feedback section in US Visa scheduling website. Write them in detail along with your appointment details and mention your query. Ask them if your mom can continue with the appointment. I have seen in the past that they have detached the applications and let the other person have the interview in such scenarios.
You can apply for a US visa from different country and get it processed. Although you cannot use the same fee receipt IMO since the conversion rates and currency are different.
